# First time Xubuntu user

Tags: xubuntu

I hope  this is a pretty basic problem but I opted to 'try' rather than 'install' Xubuntu, however I can't get back to my original operating system.

A friend said all I'd need to do was re-start and the original OS would boot but this is not the case.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Many thanks

Will

Comment: Are you sure you're not booting your Xubuntu media?

Comment: "Try Ubuntu" does not make any changes to your hard drive.  Remove the Ubuntu boot media and reboot.  You'll need to tell us what is actually happening for us to be able to help you. We can't see your screen.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the media from your PC of which you're running Xubuntu from and reboot.

E.g: If you've tried it from a CD/DVD, remove that from the optical drive. If you put it on a USB flash drive, remove the USB flash drive.